# how can I display the following code in php according to DateOfHearing (ascending order)in a html table

Tags: php, html

i have the following tables that i want to display case number, defendant name,accussed name, judge name, date of hearing and type of hearing

```
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $row['CaseNO'];?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['DefendantName'];?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['AccussedName'];?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['JudgeName'];?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['DateOfHearing'];?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['TypeOfHearing'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: can you include the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: while fetching from db you can sort

Comment: Post your full code

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the the records according to the date of hearing in your query. And simply put it in echo.

Here is a snippet :

```
<?php
$connect=new mysqli("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($connect,'database');
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM table_name");
echo"<table><tr>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
echo '<td>Case Number: '.$row['case_number'].'</td><td>Defendant Name: '.$row['defendant_name'].'</td><td>Accused name: '.$row['accused_name'].'</td><td>judge name: '.$row['judge_name'].'</td><td>Date of HEaring: '.$row['date_of_hearing'].'</td><td>type of hearing: '.$row['type_of_hearing'].'</td>';
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

According to my comments
You can directly give ASC or DESC command in query. Like:

```
SELECT column_name, column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC, column_name ASC|DESC;
```

Comment: You just put the condition the way you want the result. Rest is fine.

Comment: The issue is the sorting part

Comment: You can directly give ASC or DESC command in query. Like SELECT column_name, column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC, column_name ASC|DESC;

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS MY WHOLE CODE

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$valueToSearch=$_POST['valueToSearch'];
$query="SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE CONCAT (`CaseNO`, `JudgeName`,   `DefendantName`, `AccussedName`, `DateOfHearing`, `TypeOfHearing`) LIKE   '%".$valueToSearch. "%'";
$search_result=filterTable($query);

}
else
{
 $query="SELECT `CaseNO`,`DefendantName`,`AccussedName`,`JudgeName`,`DateOfHearing`,`TypeOfHearing`
FROM cases";
$search_result=filterTable($query);
}
function filterTable($query)
{
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mlc");

$filter_Results=mysqli_query($connect, $query);
return $filter_Results;
}

?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title> CAUSE LIST</title>
 <style>
 table,tr,th,td
 {

 }

 </style>
</head>
<BODY>
<form action="tables.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="value to search">     <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="filter" ><br><br>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Case number</th>
<th>Defendant Name</th>
<th>Accussed Name</th>
<th>Judge name</th>
<th>Date of Hearing</th>
<th>Type of Hearing</th>
</tr>
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
 <tr>
 <td> <?php echo $row['CaseNO'];?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['DefendantName'];?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['AccussedName'];?></td>
 <td> <?php echo $row['JudgeName'];?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['DateOfHearing'];?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['TypeOfHearing'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
</table>
</form>
</BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: IT WORKED BUT IT IS ORDERING BY DATE ALONE NOT THE YEAR NOR MONTHLY

Answer (score 0):

In select query you just give asscending order

```
SELECT CaseNO,DefendantName,AccussedName,JudgeName,DATE(DateOfHearing) AS DateOfHearing,TypeOfHearing 
    FROM tblname    
        ORDER BY DateOfHearing
```

Or use jquery datatable https://www.datatables.net/